# Kubernetes - connection timeout on one node with Istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway, calico

I have something really strange in my Kubernetes cluster running on prem, and I can t find it out why ...

I have a 7 nodes cluster running (5 Linux/Debian 11 and 2 Windows 2022 node) ;

Calico seems to be correctly installed and working see below (from server 175.3) :

[image]

Istio is also configured and deployed to get external connection from 3 servers (via an external load balancer)

[image]

Now the issue is, when trying to reach an application (K8S dashboard or any others) ; everything works when using IP 175.3 and 175.4 ; but I get a connection timeout on IP 175.11

Does someone have any idea why ? There is no firewall configured on the hosts, everything has been installed at the same time using the same debian image.

From server 175.11, I'm also not able to curl any services running on the Kubernetes cluster, I'm getting a timeout.

Do you have any suggestions or log that I can activate to get an idea about the issue.

Thx,

Comment: Have you tried to see if there is any error on that Node? Maybe starting from the logs of the calico daemon and finally the logs of the kubelet.

Comment: If you find anything, please share it in the question core.